# Plain text values in encrypted cookie Slim framework

Tags: session-cookies, slim, encryption

Documentation for Slim framework  says it uses encrypted cookies for login. http://docs.slimframework.com/#Cookie-Session-Store

However, when I built my login system and inspected cookie values by Chrome extension for this, I found that there are plain text values in cookie. I thought I have done something wrong, so I downloaded example app by slimframework staff member https://github.com/briannesbitt/Slim-ContextSensitiveLoginLogout
..and checked value. It still looks something like this:

```
a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22slim.flash%22%3Ba%3A0%3A%7B%7Ds%3A4%3A%22user%22%3Bs%3A16%3A%22brian%40nesbot.com%22%3B%7D
```

We can clearly see "slim.flash", "user" session variable names, email.. How can this be normal if cookie is "encrypted" ?

You can check configuration in github link's index.php

Comment: Any update? Otherwise others may thing that slim has this bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default **Slim** configuration has cookies.encrypt set to false. In that example, you've:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
```

Configure it to:

```
$app = new \Slim\Slim(array(
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
    'cookies.cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
    'cookies.cipher_mode' => MCRYPT_MODE_CBC
));
```

Also, if you're using mcrypt as the above example don't forget to install the extension.

Comment: Yes. I did a mistake by assuming this can be configured when instantiating middleware. This solved it.